# Yahoo Group Authentication

Tags: email, openid, yahoo-mail, yahoo-api

Is it possible to verify that an email address is a member of certain yahoo group? For example if user sign in with openId, can we autheticate he is member of any group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no API for Yahoo Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is one. But its use is restricted for non-commercial purposes only. Below is the link, if anyone is interested:

http://upcoming.yahoo.com/services/api/

Comment: Right, that's for Yahoo Upcoming service, but not for Yahoo Groups. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: There is a set of group related api

Comment: Ahh, right. There is a set of APIs related to [Upcoming Groups](http://upcoming.yahoo.com/group/), but I think the original question here was about [Yahoo Groups](http://groups.yahoo.com/) which are separate.

Comment: I guess I confused it with Yahoo Groups.